# Inserting Rows to SQL SERVER using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am having terrible time connecting to SQL Server using `pyodbc` from the linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04).

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={FreeTDS};PORT=**; SERVER=**; DATABASE=**;UID=AA;PWD=hfghj;')
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.fast_executemany = True
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.STG_CONTACTABILITY_SCORE VALUES (?" + ",?"*21 + ")"
sql_data = list(map(tuple, i.values))
curr.executemany(query, sql_data)
```

I am getting following error:

> ('HY004', '[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid data type (0)
>   (SQLBindParameter)')

The same insert query works from my windows laptop when I change the connection string to:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};PORT=**; SERVER=**; DATABASE=**; UID=AA; PWD=hfghj;')
```

If I change the `Driver` from `FreeTDS` to `SQL SERVER` on my Linux machine
 I get the following error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I searched for answers but there isn't much out there that could solve mine problem. 
What is the driver to connect to SQL SERVER from Linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the driver to connect to SQL SERVER from Linux machine?

If you install Microsoft's ODBC driver as described in

[Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)

then you can use `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` or `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` depending on which version you choose.

Comment: Hi @Gord Thompson: I have installed ODBC driver 17 from the link you mentioned and changing to `DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` gives _('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")_ error

Comment: Does the file `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1` exist? (It should be ~16.5 MB.)

Comment: I got it working. After I edited the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and added the description and driver pointing to `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1`. Thank you for your time.